How do I export a list as an Excel file using openpyxl?
I am working on a proof-of-concept script where I take an Excel spreadsheet and import it to a list in Python using the openpyxl module. I then make some changes to the data in the list, and export the modified list as a new Excel file.
I used the below bit of code to import the Excel data, which works great; but I can't seem to find out how to export the list back to a new Excel file. Any ideas?
path = "xyz"
l_data = load_workbook(path)
sheet = l_data.active
c_row = sheet.max_row
c_column = sheet.max_column
out_data=[]
dict={}
for a in range(1, c_row + 1):
    for b in range(1, c_column + 1):
        ob = sheet.cell(row=a, column=b)
        dict[b] = ob.value

    out_data.append(str(dict))

print(out_data)

Now the idea is to script in some changes to the "out_data" list; and then save the modified "out_data" list as a different Excel file.

If you have data in a list to write to Excel using Openpyxl, usually use the append method to do so.

How do you update data ? that is, is the newValue a function of oldValue, or your new data will be completely independent of your old data?  if the new data is 1.2 * old data, then you can do something like this in your double for loop: ws.cell(row=a, column=b).value = ws.cell(row=a, column=b).value * 1.2; if your new data has absolutely nothing to do with your old data, then better write them in a new list, and use append.

dict[b] will overwrite the value for each row. Please use the API we provide.
